# Error on installing XDebug 2.9.0 on Vagrant

Tags: php, vagrant, xdebug

I'm currently attempting to upgrade Xdebug 2.8.1 to 2.9.0 in order to resolve performance issues on code coverage report generation as reported in https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1717.

My system is Ubuntu 19.10, running a Vagrant VM with Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch). The VM has multiple versions of PHP running, to support multiple applications on our stack. Those versions are 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, and 7.4.

The only version of Xdebug available through apt is version 2.8.1, so I've attempted the following methods:

1. Using Pecl, with `apt-get install php-dev`, `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net`, and `pecl install xdebug`.
2. Using the Xdebug wizard at https://xdebug.org/wizard, which has instructions for manually unpacking the .tgz file, compiling the xdebug.so, and placing it in the correct folder.

However, in both of these methods, when adding `zend_extension=/path/to/xdebug.so` to the appropriate php.ini file and restarting the web server, I'm given the following error: `Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_post_startup_cb`.

Can anyone provide further guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to the problem.

When installing `php-dev` the package selected at the time of this writing is for PHP 7.3, when the server's default PHP version is 7.1. By installing `php7.1-dev` I was able to perform the install using either of the above processes without issue.